# Modeling heat and mass transfer modes inside rapidly rotating cylinder

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, modeling

My question is about simultaneous heat and mass transfer in rotating cylinder system. System can be detailed as:

1. A rotating cylinder contains wet porous substance in a lump shape.
2. Air stream enters the cylinder axially and can exit it by perforations on back surface of cylinder or radially by perforations on its curved surface.
3. Entering air flow is slightly higher temperature than porous medium and carries moisture from surface of porous medium.
4. RPM of cylinder is about +/- 25 for most of 1 hrs' run time. But for 5 minutes in middle of runtime gets as high as 1400 RPM.

In low RPM period, I have modeled the system's heat and mass transfer w.r.t. NTU analogy. Equations are roughly as follows:

$Re = \frac{ \dot{m_{air}} D_{drum}}{\mu m_{porous}}  $,
$Pr = \frac{Cp_{air} \mu}{k_{air}}$

$j = a Re^{-b}$, 
$ NTU = \frac{j}{Pr^{\frac{2}{3}}} $

$h_{porous \, air} A_{cylinder} = (NTU)\times \dot{m_{air}} Cp_{air}  $

$Q_{air\, to\, porous } = h_{porous \, air} A_{cylinder} \times (T_{air} - T_{porous})$

Mass transfer is characterized based on NTU too. Driving force is partial pressure difference.

Main source of heat transfer is temperature difference b/w inflowing air and porous substance, $ T_{air} = T_{porous} + 45$ at start. For mass transfer $(X_{saturation at porous surface} - X_air)$, mole-fraction difference between input air water content and saturated layer at porous substance's surface.

**I want to know, how would heat transfer conditions change under very high RPM. It will be a completely mixed system with more resistance to axial flow than before. So would NTU analogy still be used under such conditions? If not, how can I modify or replace it?**

Simple figures for system:- 
[image: System at low RPM]

[image: System at high RPM]

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is the pressure differential across the porous medium significant? Or put differently, is the rotation of the cylinder increasing the pressure differential by a significant amount? Hard to believe that it would, but unknowable with the data given. Why do you say there will be more resistance to axial flow?

Comment: AT high RPM, The porous material spreads out along the curved surface of cylinder and covers all perforations present on its curved surface. Air can only pass through perforation on its back surface. Also I assume that at such high RPM flow pattern inside drum will be predominantly rotational .  Though I suppose I should have said, **overall pressure drop for flow through drum** increases rather than more resistance to axial flow. Anyway, I wanted to know how heat/mass characteristics change during such state.

Comment: Don't you mean "more resistance to radial flow"? If you are covering the lateral openings, mass can only flow out of the end. I am beginning to think this is more an engineering than physics question... and that the problem is insufficiently well described to make much progress answering it. At least I don't know how to answer it.

Comment: Hi Floris, First of all, thank you for taking time and commenting. I should have added figures with original problem. I have added them now. I would also like to add that, I am not much interested in pressure drop or flow profile but its effect on heat/mass transfer. I have empirical data for pressure drop. What I really wanted to know is how in system with high RPM, heat/mass transfer happens. And yes, it is engineering problem. I thought this  falls under heat transfer physics. But If you can direct me to proper forum for this, that would be very appreciated too.

Comment: Hi Floris, I have put up flag for moving the question. Thanks for that. Heat source is air, which is at 40 C higher temp at start than wet porous substance. Cylinder metal and porous substance being the heat sink.  For mass transfer wet porous substance and saturated air layer that forms on its surface is the source. Air carries the moisture out, drying the porous substance.

Comment: All that is absolutely crucial information. Recognize that this is a site of physicists, not mind readers... :-)

Comment: In most heat transfer problems where evaporation is involved, the latent heat of evaporation is the primary heat transfer mechanism. You'll need to model the moisture content of the porous media to adequately predict evaporation rates, but my initial guess is that the increased surface area during the spin up time will dramatically increase the evaporation rate.